Window function formula in excel
I have a Snowflake statement below, where it calculates the 7 days spend amount with the sum of total_spend column and partition by country and id columns order by date column.
sum(total_spend) over(partition by (country, ID) order by date rows between 7 preceding and 1 preceding) as 7days_spend

Below is the Excel table that I have created from the snowflake results



DATE
WINDOW_DATE
TOTAL_SPEND




2023-10-11
2023-10-04
null


2023-10-13
2023-10-06
2078


2023-10-16
2023-10-09
7876



In the above table I have calculated window_date as A2-7 which gives the dates of DATE-7days.
Now I want to get the formula to calculate the 7days_spend value.
Below table is the expected results



DATE
WINDOW_DATE
TOTAL_SPEND
7days_spend




2023-10-11
2023-10-04
null
null


2023-10-13
2023-10-06
2078
null


2023-10-16
2023-10-09
7876
2078



In the above table 7days_spend columns is the 7 days window function calculated by me manually.
I am stuck with the excel formula to get the above result.
Please suggest different types of approaches.

Test this formula
=SUM(IF((A$2:A$5<A2)*(A$2:A$5>B2)=1,C$2:C$5,0))
Result

or try this formula a little clearer
=SUMIFS(C$2:C$5,A$2:A$5,"<"&A2,A$2:A$5,">"&B2)
Verbose description from Microsoft  or W3Schools

could you please explain the formula?

@test pls. find the edited answer.
